# Upperbound for $ \sum _{i=1}^N a_i\ln a_i $

Tags: inequality, logarithms

It's easy to prove that following upperbound is true:

$\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\ln a_i \le A \ln A$, where $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i=A$ and $ a_i\ge 1$

I'm wondering, is there stronger upperbound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the following estimate
$$\sum_{j=1}^{N} a_j\ln a_j \leq A\ln (A-N+1) .$$

Comment: Could you tell me more about this ? It is very interesting to me since the lhs is a part of entropy.